# Xslt/XML: How to dynamically compute a split point from an input value

Tags: xml, xslt, split, sum

Given the below xml input:

```
<shipment>
    <goodsLines>FP-1|HP-0|QP-3|MQP-2</goodsLines>
    <Barcodes>Code1|Code2|Code3|Code4|Code5|Code6</Barcodes>
</shipment>
```

and the desired output:

```
<Consignment>
    <GoodsItemSet>
        <GoodsItem goodsItemId="1">
            <NumberOfPackages unitCode="PCE">1</NumberOfPackages>
            <PackageTypeCode>FP</PackageTypeCode>
        </GoodsItem>
        <Package packageId="Code1"/>
    </GoodsItemSet>
    <GoodsItemSet>
        <GoodsItem goodsItemId="2">
            <NumberOfPackages unitCode="PCE">3</NumberOfPackages>
            <PackageTypeCode>QP</PackageTypeCode>
        </GoodsItem>
        <Package packageId="Code2"/>
        <Package packageId="Code3"/>
        <Package packageId="Code4"/>
    </GoodsItemSet>
    <GoodsItemSet>
        <GoodsItem goodsItemId="3">
            <NumberOfPackages unitCode="PCE">2</NumberOfPackages>
            <PackageTypeCode>MQP</PackageTypeCode>
        </GoodsItem>
        <Package packageId="Code5"/>
        <Package packageId="Code6"/>
    </GoodsItemSet>
</Consignment>
```

The idea is to recursively split by pipe, and create a GoodsItemSet for each pipe-separated GoodsLines value, with number of packages = the value after '-'. We don't do anything when the value is 0. A GoodsItemSet will have 1..* child Packages depending again on the stated number, and the id is to be extracted sequentially: 1. FP-1 => 1 barcode, from 1 to 1. 2.QP-3 => 3 barcodes, from 2 to 5, etc. The starting point for barcode reading will start at 'sum until now' +1.

How do I modify my xslt below, to dynamically change the start point and pair the right Barcode(s) to the right GoodsItemSet? The solution will be running on Biztalk 2013R2 (xslt1.0)
Much appreciated.

My xslt so far:

```
<xsl:template match="GoodsLines" name="GenerateGoodsItemSet">
    <xsl:param name="packagingCodes" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="unitsAccum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="separator" select="'|'" />

    <xsl:variable name="headpackagingCode">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($packagingCodes, $separator)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($packagingCodes, $separator)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$packagingCodes"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="tailpackagingCodes" select="substring-after($packagingCodes, $separator)" />

    <xsl:if test="number(substring-after($headpackagingCode, '-')) &gt;0">
        <xsl:element name="GoodsItemSet">
            <xsl:element name="GoodsItem">
                <xsl:attribute name="goodsItemId">
                    <xsl:number/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="NumberOfPackages">
                    <xsl:attribute name="unitCode">
                        <xsl:text>PCE</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($headpackagingCode, '-')"/>
                </xsl:element>

                <xsl:element name="PackageTypeCode">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($headpackagingCode, '-')" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>

            <!-- extract packageIds -->
    <xsl:variable name="totalPackagesSoFar" select="substring-after($headpackagingCode, '-')"/> <!--Here I need a logic for the total processed so far, to use it as a starting point.-->
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="../Barcodes">
                        <xsl:with-param name="start">1</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="stop" select="number($unitsAccum + number(substring-after($headpackagingCode,'-')))"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="../Barcodes">
                        <xsl:with-param name="start" select="number($unitsAccum + $totalPackagesSoFar) +1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="stop" select="$unitsAccum + $totalPackagesSoFar + number(substring-after($headpackagingCode,'-'))"/> 
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="$tailpackagingCodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="GenerateGoodsItemSet">
            <xsl:with-param name="packagingCodes" select="$tailpackagingCodes" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template> 

<!--Tokenizer template-->
    <xsl:template name="tokenize" match="Barcodes">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:param name="pos" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="start"/>
    <xsl:param name="stop"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
            <xsl:if test="$pos &gt;= $start and $pos &lt;= $stop">
                <xsl:element name="Package">
                    <xsl:attribute name="packageId">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:if test="$pos &gt;= $start and $pos &lt;= $stop">
                <xsl:element name="Package">
                    <xsl:attribute name="packageId">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="start" select="$start"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="stop" select="$stop"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is an awful lot of work. Which XSLT processor are you using? You could really use some help from extension functions.

Comment: Instead of starting from scratch to select the barcodes for each item set, pass the appropriate tail of the bar code list as a template parameter, similar to how you already handle the packaging codes.  You can use a separate recursive template to produce the needed tail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rare to see such an unfriendly format for the input XML. The way I would approach this is to start by restructuring the input into something workable by preprocessing the two nodes into something like:

```
<barcodes>
  <token>Code1</token>
  <token>Code2</token>
  <token>Code3</token>
  <token>Code4</token>
  <token>Code5</token>
  <token>Code6</token>
</barcodes>

<sets-rtf>
  <set type="FP" qty="1"/>
  <set type="HP" qty="0"/>
  <set type="QP" qty="3"/>
  <set type="MQP" qty="2"/>
</sets-rtf>
```

If your processor supports the EXSLT `str:tokenize()` extension function, this is rather easy to do. Otherwise you will need to employ recursive named templates to produce this interim result.

Once you have the input in the above shape, things get much easier. Here's a complete stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0 (with EXSLT)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- pre-process barcodes -->
<xsl:variable name="barcodes" select="str:tokenize(/shipment/Barcodes, '|')" />

<!-- pre-process sets -->
<xsl:variable name="sets-rtf">
    <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(/shipment/goodsLines, '|')" >
        <set type="{substring-before(., '-')}" qty="{substring-after(., '-')}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- output-->
<xsl:template match="/shipment">
    <Consignment>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($sets-rtf)/set[@qty > 0]">
            <GoodsItemSet>
                <GoodsItem goodsItemId="{position()}">
                    <NumberOfPackages unitCode="PCE">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@qty"/>
                    </NumberOfPackages>
                    <PackageTypeCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
                    </PackageTypeCode>
                </GoodsItem>
                <xsl:call-template name="generate-packages">
                    <xsl:with-param name="start" select="sum(preceding-sibling::set/@qty)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="qty" select="@qty"/>
                </xsl:call-template>                
            </GoodsItemSet>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Consignment>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-packages">
    <xsl:param name="start"/>
    <xsl:param name="qty"/>
    <xsl:if test="$qty > 0">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-packages">
            <xsl:with-param name="start" select="$start"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="qty" select="$qty - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <Package packageId="{$barcodes[$start + $qty]}"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hats off @michael.hor257k, your suggestion works beautifully! I just had to  use msxsl node-set(), and just like that my headache disappeared. U r the man :-)